# Best practices for deploying a Django app on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment

I'm developing a Django app and I'm about 50% done. I'm at a place where I want to start showing it to people, hence I need to deploy it. I've already decided that I will host it on Heroku. I want to do it properly from the start, hence my list of questions below...

Here's the current state of things:

- I want to use the new pipelines feature in Heroku.That way I can
  easily move between staging and production versions of my app.
- I want to use a CI server (at the moment I'm looking at circleci.com)
- I'm using Python 3.5
- I want to automate as much as possible in the deployment
  process, such as running migrations and tests (if needed) etc.
- Not sure if it matters, but my code is hosted in Bitbucket

**So, my questions are:**

1. The CI server obviously runs the tests. Should I run my tests on
   both the staging and production dyno's on Heroku as well?
2. Should I deploy directly to Heroku from the CI server?
3. What tools should I use to automate deployment? I can't use fabric    (python2 only), [invoke](http://www.pyinvoke.org/) doesn't look production ready. Is it fine if I just write my own simple deployment script?
4. Then there's a bunch of other tools such as docker and tox that I've read about, but I'm not really sure if I need any of them?
5. Anything else I should keep in mind when deploying a Django app to Heroku?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It's not clear for me whether you want to run unit tests or acceptance tests, but surely I wouldn't run them in production. (AT's would mess up your data - if you are doing analytics)
2. The answer to your second question depends on preferences. The actual continuous integration would mean, that if you push something to master, and it passes every test, then it can go, so it goes live. It's a nice idea, but what if you want a feature to go live at a specific time, and you don't want to mess with feature switches? I think a pressing a button is not too painful.
3. I think bash scripts are good enough to streamline the build (I'm saying this after wasting 2 days on a grunt flow..)
4. Docker is a great tool for multiple reasons, but if you're building a single Django app, I think there's no need to use it. It just makes things even harder (and I guess that would mean +1 thing you are not experienced with yet, so it could potentially cause a lot of headaches)
5. Be sure that you Django secret is not committed to bitbucket: https://github.com/matyasfodor/todo-django/blob/911614c7e41f58debe4a6369c9f0fa3cad0c52a2/todo/settings.py#L23 (and no other secret is..)

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. As for point 1, I'm talking about unit tests. Should I be running unit tests on the Heroku staging server? What about running it on the production server? When I develop and test locally, the test runner creates a separate test database that it destroys after the tests have run, leaving my current DB in tact. I assume I can do something similar when running the tests on Heroku, or is this not the case?

Comment: From my opinion the point of unit tests is validating the functionality inside the function, and the environment should be mocked. So there's no reason to run them in production, unit tests should only run on the CI server, not on staging or production server.